# how do I send userid/password in an https session

Tags: authentication, https, fiddler

I've built a request in Fiddler and need to send authentication info with the https request.  Where would I put these credentials and tell Fiddler to use them?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an Authorization line like this to the Request Headers:

```
Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0
```

This is assuming Basic authentication and dGVzdDp0ZXN0 is the Base64 encoded username and password in the form

```
username:password
```

You can use the TextWizard from within fiddler (Tools -> TextWizard) to generate the Base64 string.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing fiddler I'd assume:

```
protocol://user:password@hostname:port/
```

Answer (score 0):

That entirely depends on what kind of authentication mechanism the server is using. Most web servers use Basic, Digest, or Negotiate authentication; all convey the credentials via the WWW-Authorization request header.